# Where do I find the left arm in Yorunokasou?

Tags: yorunokasou

Where do I find the top-left inventory item in the homebrew Game Boy game [Yorunokasou](https://owarino.xyz/yoruno/)? I've looked around and found every other item.

[image: Inventory in Yorunokasou]

A screenshot on the [author's website](https://owarino.xyz/yoruno/) shows that the top left item is an arm but I can't find it.

[image: Author screenshot with arm]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's located on the Moon, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

Here's a [video walkthrough](https://youtu.be/P6QiNkuK4dA?t=4353) for that part.

(Feel free to add a spoiler if you think it's necessary)

Comment: That was an 80 minute video with 7 views in 6 months. I can't believe you found that.

Comment: So 6 views until yesterday :)